# Un-quitable buffers

Tags: emacs

For some reason I can not kill certain buffers (and therefore also
can not quit Emacs cleanly). Only the following message is displayed:

`equal: Wrong type argument: listp, \.\.\.`

The only work-around I found is to do `write-file` and save it under a
different name - then I can kill both the original and the new
buffer. However once I reopen the original file I am back to the
original error message. I can't say why or when this happens for some of the buffers. It might be I activate unwittingly some sort of protection?

This makes my work quite hard so I'll appreciate any ideas!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried -q? Could you write the cmd-line you use for opening the file?

Comment: It is in GUI (Emacs 23, Mac OS X). When I run in on command-line the result is the same, but I have to use emacsclient which doesn't recognize -q (and unlike the GUI can be quitted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your initialization file.  Turn on `debug-on-error` and see
if you can get a backtrace. [Binary Search](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.emacs.help/JomGnVm9uNE/_vzwyid9bv0J) to find it.

However before you start down that road, check if you have a package that
saves settings across Emacs sessions.  I've seen very similar issues when
[session](http://emacs-session.sourceforge.net/), but it may manifest itself with other similar packages.

The issue is some data structure being saved is too big, so Emacs abbreviates
it to "...", and when you start Emacs the next time, it gets restored /wrong/.

Comment: Thank you. I do use desktop-recover for sessions. I've tried to restart Emacs without loading the files. When I manually reopen the file that usually exhibits this behavior it still gives the same error. This is an org-mode file, while other org-mode files work OK. I noticed the behavior in few other files (e.g. in python-mode), but I can not recreate this consistently.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't loaded desktop-recover?  Note you should not load the package at all, i.e. start emacs from `emacs -Q` and load your init except anything possibly related to desktop-recover.

Comment: Turned out to be a problem with the visual bookmarks library (bm.el, seems to be a problem when I've put a persistent bookmark on a org-mode link). Since I wouldn't have solved this without `debug-on-error` I accept your answer as solution. Thank you!